# Change textview color of specific list item without user interaction in android

Tags: android, listview

I have an `ArrayList<String>` and some data in it . I am passing it to my Custom  ArrayAdapter Constructor along with other items.In the getView method I am checking the `Arraylist<String>` item with the listitems.

If they are same then I want to change the color of the textview in the Listview.  It changes the color for some items but when I scroll the Listview it changes the color of other items not in the `ArrayList<String>` passed.

Below is the code of my constructor and getView() method :

```
   public CustomMenuArrayAdapter(Context ctx,int res,String[] menuName,String[] menuDesc,String[] menuIngred,String[] menuPrice,List orderNames){
   super(ctx,res,menuName);
   this.ctx=ctx;
   this.menuName=menuName;
   this.menuDesc=menuDesc;
   this.menuIngred=menuIngred;
   this.menuPrice=menuPrice;
   this.orderNames=orderNames;
   this.inflaters=LayoutInflater.from(ctx); 
}     


   @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHold;
    View v=convertView;
    if(v==null){
        viewHold=new ViewHolder();
        v=inflaters.inflate(R.layout.category_details,parent,false);
       // viewHold.txtQtys=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
        viewHold.txtAdd=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtAdd);
        viewHold.txtPrices=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtPrices);
        viewHold.txtName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtCatNameDetails);
        viewHold.txtDesc=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtCatDescDetails);
        viewHold.txtIngred=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtIngredientDetails);
       // viewHold.add=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgPlus);
       // viewHold.sub=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgMinus);
        v.setTag(viewHold);
       // viewHold.txtName.setTag(position);
    }else{
        viewHold=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
    }

   if(orderNames.get(0)!=null || !orderNames.get(0).equals("")) {
           for(int k=0;k<orderNames.size();k++) {
               Log.e("k:----->"+k," menuN:"+menuName[position]+"<--->"+orderNames.get(k));
               if (orderNames.get(k).toString().equals(menuName[position])) {
                    TextView txt=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtCatNameDetails);
                    txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                   break;
               }

               }
           }

    viewHold.txtName.setText(menuName[position]);
    viewHold.txtDesc.setText("Desc: "+menuDesc[position]);
    viewHold.txtIngred.setText("Ingred: "+menuIngred[position]);
    viewHold.txtPrices.setText("UGX : " + menuPrice[position]);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: set default backgroundcolor in else condition and LTGRAY In if condition ..

Comment: @priyankamorisetti i tried , it's not working

Comment: whats the negative rating for , i am not able to get the answer and you are giving a negative rating instead of trying to post an answer

Comment: negative rating?? .. thats not me who rated down vote , why should i give negative rating , if u get the answer then i will learn something from that ...

Comment: i didn't took your name ,i am pointing out to the person who have downvoted

Comment: Try  viewHold.txtName.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY); instead of  TextView txt=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtCatNameDetails);
                    txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY); in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your logic is sound. For instance, this looks wrong:

```
if (orderNames.get(0) != null || !orderNames.get(0).equals("")) {
    ....
}
```

First check you perform is:

```
orderNames.get(0) != null
```

The two outcomes of this check:

1. **TRUE**: `orderNames.get(0)` is not `null` ===> second check is not even performed since you are `ORing`.
2. **FALSE**: `orderNames.get(0)` is `null` ===> second check is performed since you are `ORing` ===> and this will give you a `NullPointerException` here: `!(null).equals("")`.

Does this looks better:

```
// Check if orderNames.get(0) is empty (note the use of `trim()`)
if (orderNames.get(0) != null && !orderNames.get(0).trim().equals("")) {
    ....
}
```

Even better:

```
// Rejects `null`, ""(empty string) & "    "(strings that contain only whitespaces)
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(orderNames.get(0)) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(orderNames.get(0).trim)) {
    ....
}
```

Still, I don't know what you accomplish with this check. This only confirms that the first item in the list contains a non-empty String. Later on, you iterate over the whole list and don't even perform any null or empty string checks.

I don't recommend this, but try it out. If it works, figure out why:

```
// Reset - in case this view was recycled
viewHold.txtName.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(orderNames.get(0)) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(orderNames.get(0).trim)) {
    for(int k = 0; k < orderNames.size(); k++) {
        Log.e("k:----->" + k, " menuN: " + menuName[position] + "<--->" + orderNames.get(k));

        // Can possibly throw NPE
        // If `menuName[position]` is guaranteed to be non-null, you can reverse the check
        if (orderNames.get(k).toString().equals(menuName[position])) {
            viewHold.txtName.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Your implementation of the `ViewHolder` pattern is fine.

Comment: Thanks i finally got the answer after i implemented your code

Answer (score 1):

Using ViewHolder is a good approach but replace your getView() method with below code, surly you will get what you want..........

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (convertView == null)
        {
         convertView = inflaters.inflate(R.layout.category_details, parent, false);
            TextView txtAdd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAdd);
            TextView txtPrices = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPrices);
            TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCatNameDetails);
            TextView txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtCatDescDetails);
            TextView txtIngred = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtIngredientDetails);

            if (orderNames.get(0) != null || !orderNames.get(0).equals(""))
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < orderNames.size(); k++)
                {
                    Log.e("k:----->" + k, " menuN:" + menuName[position] + "<--->" + orderNames.get(k));
                    if (orderNames.get(k).toString().equals(menuName[position]))
                    {
                        txtName.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txtName.setBackgroundColor("default color");
                    }
                }
            }
            txtName.setText(menuName[position]);
            txtDesc.setText("Desc: " + menuDesc[position]);
            txtIngred.setText("Ingred: " + menuIngred[position]);
            txtPrices.setText("UGX : " + menuPrice[position]);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: sorry friend but your code is giving me strange results like repeating the listitems because of recycling and sometimes the values is not getting the background color

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the viewholder pattern, which means that you are reusing the views gone offscreen for the views coming onscreen. This means that the viewholder will its properties eg color if you dont reset it yourself. So in your case you

```
TextView txt=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtCatNameDetails);
if (orderNames.get(k).toString().equals(menuName[position])) {
     txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
     break;
} else {
     txt.setBackgroundColor(/* default color */);
     break;
}
```

Comment: Hi Modge ,thanks for your reply,i tried resetting the color in else part to default but still i am not getting the output

Comment: Do you want to say that i should try the code without using  viewholder pattern ?

Comment: viewholder is ok, its its just where your problem is

Comment: i am not understanding what's the problem with the viewholder because i have seen a lot of reference articles but they have implemented the same way as i have

Answer (score 0):

That's because your code is wrong. You aren't using ViewHolder pattern properly. Your "else" in getView shouldn't be there.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

ViewHolder viewHold;
View v=convertView;
if(v==null){
    viewHold=new ViewHolder();
    v=inflaters.inflate(R.layout.category_details,parent,false);
   // viewHold.txtQtys=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtQty);
    viewHold.txtAdd=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtAdd);
    viewHold.txtPrices=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtPrices);
    viewHold.txtName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtCatNameDetails);
    viewHold.txtDesc=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtCatDescDetails);
    viewHold.txtIngred=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtIngredientDetails);
   // viewHold.add=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgPlus);
   // viewHold.sub=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imgMinus);
    v.setTag(viewHold);
   // viewHold.txtName.setTag(position);
}
ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
...
}
```

Comment: Hi Borja , I tried your answer but it not working still , i commented the else part and created new viewholder object but the output is that along with the items in ArrayList  other items are also getting the background color after scrolling

Comment: This part should be inside if condition:  TextView txt=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtCatNameDetails);
And then modofy this " txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);" to holder.txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);

Comment: i tried putting  the TextView code in the if condition and using the new Holder object but still different list items are getting background color

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the `ViewHolder` pattern, which means that you are reusing the views so when your `ListView` is scrolling it changes the color of other items because you are reusing your views.

You need to add these two methods to your `CustomMenuArrayAdapter` to make it working.

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
  return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
  return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

let me pretend that you used `viewHold.txtName.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);`

```
//comes below  viewHold=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();}
viewHold.txtName.setBackgroundColor(Color.Transparent);
```

*now show your love*

Answer (score 0):

Remove check `v == null (convertView)`, call `viewHold=new ViewHolder();` in every time.
I think ListView recycle is problems in your stuck.